# Capturing some different part of text and replacing with another

Tags: regex

There is a deprecated function in PHP and for that reason, I need to replace all functions with their replacements. Since some of the arguments have different values, I need to use a regex find-and-replace method to do this.

For example I have two functions:

```
mysql_result($one,0,"val1")
mysql_result($two,0,"val2")
```

How can I write a regex to convert this two into those?

```
$one["val1"]
$two["val2"]
```

Currently I have `(mysql_result\()*\"\)` but this only matches the ending part of the function.

Comment: There is no need to use regex since you'll need to manually edit them to use prepared statements. Sometimes, you shouldn't be lazy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern, then substitute with `$1["$2"]`:

```
.*?\(([^,]+).*?"([^"]+).*
```

[`Live DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/gZ7nU4)

**Edit:**

```
$string = array('mysql_result($one,0,"val1")', 'mysql_result($two,0,"val2")');

$pattern = '/.*?\(([^,]+).*?"([^"]+).*/';

print_r( preg_replace($pattern, '$1["$2"]', $string ));
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://codepad.org/vALJuObX)

Comment: Thanks, but how about replacement value? Could you try it [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... It works [HERE](http://regexr.com?37cn9) as well...

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/mysql_result\(([^,]*),[^,]*,([^)]*)\)/', '$1[$2]', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following regexRegEx: `(mysql_result\()(.*),(.*),(.*)(\))` 
And replace it with following: `\2[\4]`

Comment: This worked, but also captured the following stuff after function. Eg: `mysql_result($sql,0,"id")."'>$edit</a>]</font>");`